# Visual Studio WinForms Groupbox is not displayed after I have moved it in the Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm currently working on a C# Windows Forms project and facing issues displaying a GroupBox correctly. I work in the Designer and move the different groupboxes around. I place my groupbox on the edges of the form in my Designer and display them as follows:

```
groupbox.Visible = true;
groupbox.Location = new Point(221, 74);
groupbox.Size = new Size(716, 487);
```

Despite these settings, the GroupBox does not appear on the form. I've tried changing the background color, calling the BringToFront method, and refreshing the window, but the problem persists.
If I move the groupbox my code in the Designer file is changing, for example it removes the

```
Control.Add(groupbox);
```

Are there any other aspects I might have overlooked, or do you have suggestions on how to solve this issue? Perhaps someone has had similar experiences and can provide guidance.

Thank you in advance!

1. WinForms Application is working properly
2. Move a groupbox in the Designer
3. Groupbox is not displaying anymore in the running Application

Comment: Open up the Document Outline pane (CTRL+ALT+T) and verify what is the Parent of that GroupBox -- Don't modify the designer file manually, read the warnings at the top of the file

Comment: This one fixed the Problem. Thank you Jimi!

Comment: @unknownuser93 Hi, I posted an answer based on Jimi's point of view. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 0):

As from the designer file ***this.Controls.Add(this.groupbox)*** is removed, Which means it has not been added to the Form.

If you initialise the group box control properly and add that to the Form by ***this.Controls.Add(this.groupbox)***, it will show in the defined location and will be visible in the Form.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jimi.

You can open the Document Outline pane (CTRL+ALT+T) and find the parent of the GroupBox.

In Visual Studio, on the View menu, click Other Windows and then click Document Outline.

For Windows Forms applications in Visual Studio, you can use the document outline to perform these tasks:

View the logical structure of a Form or a UserControl.

Put user input focus on deeply nested controls that may be hard to select on the Form itself or the UserControl itself.

Move controls from one parent to another parent.

Locate controls that may be visually hidden by other controls.

For Windows Forms applications, a document outline is displayed only in Design view for a Form or a UserControl. Nothing is displayed in Code view.